# Vba function evaluated by named parameters

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to invoke a function by specifying what the named parameters should be?

So for example if you have

```
Public function tmp(optional Byref a as integer=2, optional Byref b as integer=10)

    Tmp=a*b

End function
```

I want to use the above by tmp(b=5). Hope someone can help.

Comment: Try: `tmp(b:=5)`

Comment: It works if the function is invoked from another function or sub. But is it possible to do same when the function I called from a cell?

Comment: you will call it the same way as described by T.M., One or both of your arguments will be a cell reference. example: in cell B2, put `=tmp(,A2)`. If A2 value is 76, then the answer in B2 will be 152. And your arguments should be `ByVal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to pass only Argument b:

```
Debug.Print tmp(, 5)     ' results in 2 * 5 = 10
```

or simply as mentioned in comment by @Guest

```
Debug.Print tmp(b:=5)
```

Comment: also this: `Debug.Print tmp(b:=5)`

Comment: Thanks for replying. But is it possible to do the same when the function is called from a cell? Your first suggestion I simple enough, when the numbers of parameters is limited, but as the complexity of the function grows, it will quickly become a headache.

Comment: You are welcome. - As to your question: you could pass a range argument with 2 columns defining only one or a few variables in the first column and the wanted values in the second one. To get further ideas you would need to define how you want to configure your function - could be worth to pose a new question with some more details :-) @RasmusAndersen